# Hierarchical model: does leaving out a latent variable (hierarchy level) result in an equivalent model?

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, latent-variable

Say we have a hierarchical model:

$$z_i \sim \mbox{Bernoulli}(\pi_i); \mbox{logit}(\pi_i) =  ... \text{(linear function of covariates for site i)}$$
$$y_{i,j} \sim \mbox{Bernoulli}(z_i \cdot p_{i,j}) ; \mbox{logit}(p_{i,j}) =  ... \text{(linear function of covariates for visit <i,j>)}$$

where $z_i$ is a latent variable, saying whether bird is present at site i ($z_i = 1$) or absent ($z_i = 0$); $\pi_i$ is a probability of bird being present at site $i$, which is a function of some covariates. $y_{i,j}$ is the actual observation of the bird at site $i$ during visit $j$; $p_{i,j}$ being the probability of detection of the bird which is present, i.e. $p_{i,j} = \mbox{P}(y_{i,j} = 1 | z_i = 1)$.

Because the only input data are the $y_{i,j}$ and we actually don't know $z_i$, I thought we could simplify (flatten) the model by removing the latent variable $z$ and having just:

$$y_{i,j} \sim \mbox{Bernoulli}(\pi_i \cdot p_{i,j})$$

The question is: **Is this model equivalent to the first one?** $y$-prediction-wise, coefficient-wise, everything-wise (of course everything except having $z_i$'s :-) If no, where is the difference?

My thoughts are:

- maybe it should be equivalent, because $z$ is latent, so it should be "integrated out" :-)
- maybe it shouldn't, because $z_i$ could actually transfer information between $y_{i,j}$ of the same site $i$. For example, when $y_{i,1} = 1$, the model will immediatelly know $z_i = 1$ without question, so this could somehow influence the inference for nodes $y_{i,2}$, $y_{i,3}$ etc...

Just thoughts, I'm very likely mistaken somewhere... I'd be grateful for some thoughts on the matter :-)

Thanks and have a beautiful Christmass time! :)

Comment: I think using R-specific notation for probability densities decreases readability quite a bit - a lot of people doing Bayesian statistics do not use R.

Comment: @Forgottenscience this is more like bugs (WinBUGS, JAGS, OpenBUGS) notation... but it is also pretty similar to general statistic notation... Ok I will replace `dbern` with `Bernoulli` so it's clear :-) Thanks for the comment!

Comment: In your revised model you don't mention that $y_{i,1}$ is not independent from $y_{i,2}$.  So currently your revised model is incomplete.  Your comment suggests that you already know this information is missing.

Comment: @JimB so you think the models are different, because the second one doesn't express the dependence between $y_{i,1}$ and  $y_{i,2}$? Thanks for comment! It is possible, but I'm not sure about this, because: what if in the second model their "dependence" is expressed enough by them sharing the same $\pi_i$ in their Bernoulli probabilities? Please also look at [the likelihood derivation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/442009/5509), I'm curious if I maybe made some mistake there? Thanks for contribution!

Comment: It's not that the models are different.  You just didn't express the dependence between visits at the same site.  It is that your description of your model is incomplete.  (Unless your model asserts that visits at the same site are independent which means that all site/visit combinations are independent which in term means that your model is different from the hierarchical model.)

Comment: @JimB so you are saying that the models are equivalent, but one is "incomplete" because I didn't "express" something? That doesn't make sense. There is no "express" beyond the model, if you know what I mean? The model is an exact, formal and clearly defined expression with clear boundaries. Either the models are equivalent, and then there cannot be anything "missing" to express, because the definition of both models implies the equivalence. Or one of those models is "missing" something, and then they cannot be equivalent.

Comment: Your model is still incomplete. Consider the likelihood that $y_{11}=0$ and $y_{12}=0$. That likelihood is $1−\pi_1+\pi_1(1−p_{11})(1−p_{12})=1−p_{11}\pi_1−p_{12}\pi_1+p_{11}p_{12}\pi_1$. If you multiply the associated two likelihoods that you present in your answer below, you don't get that result. Again, your approach to avoid a mention of a latent variable is not necessarily wrong. It is just incomplete.  What you need to do is show the likelihood for the resulting visit status for all visits at a single site rather than just for a particular visit at a particular site.

Comment: Maybe another way to phrase it:  You're showing the equivalent of the marginal distributions but avoiding mentioning the joint distributions.  Equivalence of marginal distributions does not imply equivalence of joint distributions.

Comment: @JimB wow, nice difference in terms. But shouldn't *marginal* likelihood be also *joint*? :-)

Comment: Here's an article that I think answers all of your questions:  https://projects.ncsu.edu/cals/course/zo501/2016%20Sampling%20Lab/MacKenzie%202002.pdf.  You might have already seen this but may others have not.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a thourough look at the likelihood function $\cal{L}(y_{ij}|\pi_i,p_{ij})$ of both models.

The likelihood function of the second model is simple:

$${\cal L}(y_{ij}|\pi_i,p_{ij}) = \mbox{Bernoulli}(y_{ij}|\pi_i \cdot p_{ij})$$

The likelihood function of the first model is the integration (summation) over all possible values of the latent variable $z$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}{\cal L}(y_{ij}|\pi_i,p_{ij}) &=& \sum_{z_i \in \{0,1\}} {\cal L}(y_{ij}|z_i,p_{ij}) \cdot {\cal L}(z_i|\pi_{i}) = \\ &=& {\cal L}(y_{ij}|z_i= 0,p_{ij}) \cdot {\cal L}(z_i=0|\pi_{i}) + {\cal L}(y_{ij}|z_i=1,p_{ij}) \cdot {\cal L}(z_i=1|\pi_{i}) = \\ &=& \mbox{Bernoulli}(y_{ij}|0)\cdot(1-\pi_i) + \mbox{Bernoulli}(y_{ij}|p_{ij})\cdot\pi_i\end{eqnarray}$$

This gives us:

$${\cal L}(y_{ij}|\pi_i,p_{ij}) = \begin{cases} 
y_{ij} = 0: & 1\cdot(1-\pi_i)+(1-p_{ij})\cdot\pi_i =1 - p_{ij}\cdot\pi_i \\ 
y_{ij} = 1: & 0 + p_{ij}\cdot\pi_i
\end{cases}$$

Which is exactly the same likelihood function as in the first model, right? This proves the models are fully equivalent, right? **Q.E.D.**, right?

## No.

The models need the *joint* likelihood to be equivalent (thanks @JimB for comment)!

So, the joint likelihood of the **second model** is again simple:

$${\cal L}(y_{i*}|\pi_i,p_{i*}) = \prod_{j} {\cal L}(y_{ij}|\pi_i,p_{ij}) = \prod_{j} \mbox{Bernoulli}(y_{ij}|\pi_i \cdot p_{ij})$$

For the **first model**, again, lets do the summation over all possible values of $z$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}{\cal L}(y_{i*}|\pi_i,p_{i*}) &=& \sum_{z_i \in \{0,1\}} {\cal L}(z_i|\pi_{i}) \prod_{j} {\cal L}(y_{ij}|z_i,p_{ij})  = \\ &=& {\cal L}(z_i=0|\pi_{i}) \prod_{j} {\cal L}(y_{ij}|z_i= 0,p_{ij})  + {\cal L}(z_i=1|\pi_{i}) \prod_{j} {\cal L}(y_{ij}|z_i=1,p_{ij})  = \\ &=& (1-\pi_i) \prod_{j} \mbox{Bernoulli}(y_{ij}|0) + \pi_i \prod_{j} \mbox{Bernoulli}(y_{ij}|p_{ij})\end{eqnarray}$$

It can be easily seen that this is *different* from the second model; here, we have only singular power of $\pi_i$, whereas in the second model, $\pi_i$ will reach the power of how many $j$ indices we have for the single $i$ index.

**So the answer is: the models are not equivalent.**

Comment: Your model is still incomplete.  Consider the likelihood that $y_{11}=0$ and $y_{12}=0$.  That likelihood is $1 - \pi_1 +  \pi_1 (1 - p_{11}) (1 - p_{12})=1 - p_{11} \pi_1 - p_{12} \pi_1 + p_{11} p_{12} \pi_1$.  If you multiply the associated two likelihoods, you don't get that result.  How does your description obtain the correct result?  Again, your approach is not wrong.  It is just incomplete.

Comment: @JimB you are right, thanks! This means I have to focus on the joint likelihood, which is *not* equivalent then!

Comment: @DrewN  You are likely correct in that I probably don't know in what the OP is interested.  My point is that the OP shows the equivalence of the marginal (site/visit) likelihoods when equivalence of models requires equivalence of joint likelihoods.

Comment: @JimB I was interested **in the equivalence of the models**, as stated in the question and comments. And, your example with $y_{i1}$ and $y_{i2}$ clearly showed the models are not equivalent, because the joint likelihood (probably the only thing that matters for the equivalence) differs. I updated this answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DrewN ok let's clean up all those comments? :-)

Comment: Sure, I've deleted all my incorrect comments, including my reply to @JimB suggesting OP was interested in something else. Thank you for the discussion. I agree that using the $z_i$'s encodes dependence between the visits in a different way than just sharing the $\pi_i$'s does, so the model ought to be different. And you see it explicitly when you write down the joint likelihood.

Comment: I would also like to observe that the use of $z_i$ and $\pi_i$ doesn't seem to help much here, since any observed visits seem to cause $\pi_i$ to always be estimated as 1, and otherwise as 0 if there are no visits, with no in-between. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

If one starts out modeling the joint probability (or equivalently the likelihood) of the status of all visits and mentions the appropriate assumptions, then one can certainly avoid talk of latent variables and construct the likelihood (although the use of latent variables is implied).

Using much of the OP's notation we assume independence of visit status between sites but because the true status of a site is assumed not to change during all visits (the "closure" assumption), a dependence among visits at site $i$ is induced:  either all visits will be zero (at an unoccupied site) or the visit status for the $v_i$ visits will vary independently according to a probability $p_{ij}$ for visits $j=1,2,\ldots,v_i$.

We also assume that there are no false positive visits and that a site with no detections could either be an unoccupied site or an occupied site.

The likelihood at a site for observed visit status $y_{i,1},y_{i,2},\ldots,y_{i,v_i}$ is given by

$$\mathcal{L}_i(y_{i,1},y_{i,2},\ldots,y_{i,v_i})=1-\pi_i+\pi_i \prod_{j=1}^{v_i}(1-p_{ij}) ~~~\text{if}~~\sum_{j=1}^{v_i} y_{ij}=0$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\pi_i \prod_{j=1}^{v_i}p_{ij}^{y_{ij}}(1-p_{ij})^{1-y_{ij}} ~~~~~~\text{if}~~\sum_{j=1}^{v_i} y_{ij}>0$$

Comment: Thanks! Now I even see the connection with the closure assumption! Amazing!

Comment: I removed the meta part of your answer @JimB. You can revert it if you feel it is pertinent to the answer though, but I don't see it as so.

Comment: @Firebug Not a problem.  It now actually looks more like an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: It's completely an answer, and it resolved OPs question as well :)

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that you've answered your own question. In your example with y[i,1]=1, occupancy (z) is known for all replicate visits to site i, so the remaining visits to the site (y[i,2...n.reps]) provide information about detection probability. It is a hierarchical model with site occupancy being estimated first, then detection being estimated within the site conditional on the site being occupied or not). If your model only uses Bernoulli(site occupancy X detection probability), the model might estimate that site i was occupied on visit 1 but not on visits 2:n.reps -- which is not consistent with the closure assumption that makes the model work.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for contribution! That was my idea too, but looking at the likelihood function in more detail ([see my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/442009/5509)), it seems like the models are actually equivalent. Please have look at it, maybe you will find some mistake in my ideas? Thanks!